# SQL prepared statement how to select via multiple possible menu selections?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

So I have 4 menu selections (product, location, courseType, and category), all of which can be null (programmed using JSF but that should be irrelevant to this question, as it is an SQL question).

The menu selection will send the managed bean the variable that the user selected, and using a prepared statement search a database table using the information from the menu that the user selected (if any).

If the user leaves the menu item null, it should search everything.

If the user leaves 1 or 2 or 3 of the menu items with information, and the other one null, it should search accordingly.

My problem is how do I do this without a bunch of if/then statements in the bean attached to an the appropriate sql statement for every one?

Or is there one better sql statement I can make that does all of this?

I am using a prepared statement in Java.

I tried this:

```
if (product != null && location != null && courseType != null && category != null) {
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * FROM Courses WHERE "
                    + "product = ? "
                    + "and location = ? "
                    + "and courseType = ? "
                    + "and category = ?");

            pstmt.setString(1, product);
            pstmt.setString(2, location);
            pstmt.setString(3, courseType);
            pstmt.setString(4, category);
        } else if (product == null && location != null && courseType != null && category != null) {
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * FROM Courses WHERE "
                    + "location = ? "
                    + "and courseType = ? "
                    + "and category = ?");


            pstmt.setString(1, location);
            pstmt.setString(2, courseType);
            pstmt.setString(3, category);
        }
```

etc etc but I would have to do this like 16 times for each case of 1 being null and not the others?
There must be a smarter way (either by using 1 sql statement or only a few java if/then statements?)

UPDATE thanks to Luiggi Mendoza! My code works like this:

```
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * FROM Courses WHERE " 
         + "(product = ? or ? is null) " 
         + "and (location = ? or ? is null) " 
         + "and (courseType = ? or ? is null)" 
         + "and (category = ? or ? is null)"); 

         pstmt.setString(1, product);
         pstmt.setString(2, product);
         pstmt.setString(3, location);
         pstmt.setString(4, location);
         pstmt.setString(5, courseType);
         pstmt.setString(6, courseType);
         pstmt.setString(7, category);
         pstmt.setString(8, category);


        rset = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Update yeah I had to use = "" instead of is null for a different mysql database (maybe different versions or something)

Answer (score 7):

I assume that you have a default value for your `NULL` selected values (since I don't know another way to do it using `PreparedStatement`) as `'0'` (just as an example).

Knowing this, I tend to use this kind of SQL:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Courses
WHERE
    (product = ? or ? = '0')
    and (location = ?  or ? = '0')
    and (courseType = ? or ? = '0')
    and (category = ? or ? = '0')
```

With this approach, you leverage the `IF` usage and let the database handle the work. The only bad point with this is that you should set every variable twice (nothing is free in this life =\ ).

---

EDIT: I've made a test based on your requirement. First the SQL table and content:

```sql
create table pruebaMultiSelect
(id int primary key auto_increment,
nombre varchar(50),
tipo varchar(10),
categoria varchar(10));

insert into pruebaMultiSelect values
(null, 'Luiggi', 'A', 'X');

insert into pruebaMultiSelect values
(null, 'Thomas', 'A', 'Y');

insert into pruebaMultiSelect values
(null, 'Jose', 'B', 'X');

insert into pruebaMultiSelect values
(null, 'Trina', 'B', 'Y');
```

Now, the relevant Java code:

```
public class DBTest {

    public void testPreparedStatement(String p1, String p2) throws SQLException {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            con = getConnection();
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM pruebaMultiSelect WHERE (tipo = ? OR ? = 'EMPTY') "
                    + "AND (categoria = ? OR ? = 'EMPTY')");
            pstmt.setString(1, p1);
            pstmt.setString(2, p1);
            pstmt.setString(3, p2);
            pstmt.setString(4, p2);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.printf("%5d %15s\n", rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2));
            }
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            rs.close();
            pstmt.close();
            con.close();
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/luiggi_test", "user", "password");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        //this will return all the data
        String p1 = "EMPTY";
        String p2 = "EMPTY";
        new DBTest().testPreparedStatement(p1, p2);
    }
}
```

Tested using MySQL 5.1.18.

Comment: yeah, I tried that before actually, and it doesn't work well. I did it like this using a preparedstatement:

pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * FROM Courses WHERE "
                        + "product = ? or product is null "
                        + "and (location = ? or location is null) "
                        + "and (courseType = ? or courseType is null)"
                        + "and (category = ? or category is null)");

Comment: That's why I don't suggest using `NULL`, instead use a default value like `'0'` or `'EMPTY'` (or another default value for `NULL`).

Comment: Hmmm that way doesn't seem to work, probably because prepared statements won't let me do '0' or 'EMPTY'. The Java class preparedstatement sends its own info to the SQL server specified by the ?

Comment: @ArmandoPerea answer updated, now it shows an example (using a different table, though).

Comment: Oh thanks for the edit, I'll try that out. I think I didn't do the pstmt.setString correctly in mine. I'll let u know if I got it working....

Comment: @ArmandoPerea un honor haberte ayudado :). Please mark the check below the rep (the number with the up/down arrows).

Answer (score 1):

I tend to build dynamic queries with helper methods like this:

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuidler();
query.append("SELECT foo, bar FROM baz");
query.append(buildProductClause(product));
query.append(buildLocationClause(location));
query.append(buildCourseTypeClause(courseType));
// etc...
```

You could use a member field to build an array of arguments if you want to still use a prepared statement.

Comment: This is a good approach but I find it very hard to maintain when you want/need to add a new column to check (and worse when you have to add new tables in the `FROM` part). I try to use this approach only if the `FROM` or the `ORDER BY` columns should be filled dynamically.