# jdbc mysql query where I am unsure how many columns are being selected

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Full disclosure: This is homework.

I have a GUI written in java that interacts with a database with 4 buttons to Add, Delete, Query and Modify.  The GUI has 6 textfields (MemberNumber, LastName, FirstName, Address, TotalRentals and Account Balance).

How would I go about writing the Query sql command that retrieves the account info based on the fields, considering I don't know beforehand which textfields might have values entered?  If it's just MemberNumber, that's the primary key, and easy.  But what if it's LastName and TotalRentals, or LastName, TotalRentals and Address?

I guess my question is, how can I make this query flexible?

Comment: Post your code, but I suspect that resultSetMetadata might sort you.

Comment: I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15122018/1065197

Comment: You need to look at the database/table metadata

Comment: Luiggi, your example did it.  Thanks!!