# Conditionally add AND conditions in Oracle SQL

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am using a String SQL query in Java where i need to conditionally ignore or add AND clauses. For example suppose below query,

```
select t.name from test t where
t.id=?
and
t.name=?
and
t.status=?
```

so its like if name is empty or null i want to ignore it and if count status is total i need to execute below condition t.status= 'cancel' and t.status = 'confirm'. Like below pseudo query but i guess i can only use conditions in stored procedures right not in normal string sql?

```
select t.name from test t where
t.id=?
and
if(t.name != null){
t.name=?
}
and
if(t.status.equals = 'total'){
t.status='total'
}else{
t.status = ?
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15122018/1065197. The example is on MySQL but works on any other RDBMS as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
May be try this technice

(:param IS NULL OR <someField> = (other condition) :param)

You query looks like

SELECT ... FROM ...
WHERE
(:param IS NULL OR <someField> = (other condition) :param)
AND
(:param1 IS NULL OR <someField> = (other condition) :param1)
```

FOR YOU Example

```
WHERE t.status = CASE WHEN t.status = 'Total' THEN 'Total' ELSE :param END
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
select t.name from test t where
t.id=?
and
(t.name=? OR t.name IS NULL)
and
(
        (t.status=? AND t.statuc <> 'total')
    OR  (t.status = 'total')
)
```