# change the select criteria according to a multiple select

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have an HTML page that contain a multiple select field, according to the selection I display some information from a sql table liek this.

```
select * from myTable where x="1" or x="2"
```

the problem is because I'm having multiple select so I dont know how many number of conditions I should provide for my sql query. like if I have just a single selection from the multiple select field, then the query will be like this:

```
select * from myTable where x="1"
```

but if I have three selections then the query will be like this:

```
select * from myTable where x="!" or x="2" or x="3"
```

so how can I write a dynamically changing query in Java that can handle single or multiple or even all selections??

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL prepared statement how to select via multiple possible menu selections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121869/sql-prepared-statement-how-to-select-via-multiple-possible-menu-selections)

Comment: Sorry, is the `x` column multiple times in your `WHERE` clause or are they different columns?

Comment: Put the select parameters into a `List`. To build the query, use an iterator to check if there are more elements left as you iterate. If there are, add an `OR` and the field you want. That would build your `PreparedStatement`. You can use the same technique to set your `?` placeholders to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL IN to avoid your situation. Something like this:

```
// this is crude way to create your SQL IN part
// Ideally you should be iterating over your selections and creating this string
String selections = firstSelection + "," + secondSelection;

select * from myTable where x IN(selections);
```

Comment: I would prefer having a `String[]`, create my query with `?` and then setting each array of the `String` to the `PreparedStatement` to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That is also a good solution. I just thought in SQL terms to help with this situation.

Comment: LuiggiMendoza and @JunedAhsan Thanks a lot for you replies guys, but I still not sure how can I change the query if I 3 or more selections for x instead of just 2? like in the multiple select I select 4 values, so how will the query will look like? thanks

Comment: @user1762447 If you have the selections and you want to use my solution then simply create the selections string with all the selections : String selections = firstSelection + "," + secondSelection + "," and so on;