# simpler sql query for filtering results or any better way?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

---

I have a page in my web application which shows all the

> ticketsid(int)
>
> summary(String)
>
> description(String)
>
> priorityId(int)
>
> statusId (int)
>
> assignedTo(String)
>
> projectId(int)
>
> ticketSubmissionDate(Date)

stored in the database and user can filter the tickets using four different fields i.e

> priorityId ,statusId , projectId and assignedTo

which are shown as drop down lists on the page where all the tickets are shown .

For this purpose what i have done , i have written queries for each combination of fields a user can select for example priority and status , status and project , status, assignedTo and project ,only priority,only status and so on is there any better or simpler way in which i can do this ?

Comment: For different result set you need different query..as simple as that..and i dont see any problem in data , depends on your select perticular query get fired. what you mean by simpler way ? unclear

Comment: then  what approach i am using is right  ?

Comment: Yes...Lets see other views also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a elegant solution proposed by Luiggi Mendoza, which allows you to do exactly, what you want, but used just one database query. [Check this out.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15122018/4073877)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a default value for your NULL selected values (since I don't know another way to do it using PreparedStatement) as '0'